# Is it possible to setup an email address for a site collection in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, sharepoint-email

Is it possible to set up an email address (using Central Admin, Powershell, .NET dev, any other form) for outgoing email from a site collection in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Where will the emails be sent from? What action sends the emails?

Comment: Hi. I am using the alert me out of the box functionality within a site collection. Can i set an outgoing email address for this site collection?

Answer (score 1):

For outgoing email, you can set it through PowerShell.

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://siteUrl
$site.OutgoingEmailAddress = 'myAddr@example.com
```

Comment: Does this work for Site Collections in SharePoint 2013 though? I tried it however the Site Collection's outgoing email address is still the same as the Farm outgoing email address.

Comment: Do you have the correct site? This is how one would set the outgoing email address for a specific Site Collection.

Comment: Hi Trevor. Yes I am using the above code for the correct site. The code is as follows:  $site = Get-SPSite https://site.intra.domain/sites/chris
$site.OutgoingEmailAddress = 'email@domain.com'    is this correct please?

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what your after but an easy inbuilt way (depending on what you already have set up) is to simply make a document library at the root site and enable incoming emails into that document library.

To enable incoming emails you need a SMTP server (I set one up on the same server that has SP) to create the domain. Using Central Admin you then enable incoming emails and create a domain name (needs to match the SMTP server domain name).

Then once enabled for the site collection go to your library and through library settings enable incoming emails. You can also set it up so when an email comes in you can get a notification about it (Alert Me or through a workflow)

Technet has a pretty decent walk through on how to do it all: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc262947.aspx 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/harmeetw/2012/12/28/sharepoint-2013-configure-incoming-emails-with-exchange-server-2013/ (Using Exchange Server)

Comment: Hi Roland  Thank you for your reply. I need this for outgoing email though

Comment: @ChrisG Ah ok, your original question did not specify that it was for out going. Trevor's answer should be what your looking for

Comment: Does Trevors answer work for Site Collections though?

Comment: Be aware that this is a "NOREPLY" email... If you want to catch the incoming mail you would need to bind it to a list also.